# Creating arrays from loops in one line

Tags: ruby

Is it possible, like in Python, to create an array from a loop in just one line? Can I make the following code in to just one line?

```
 foo = []
 bars.each do |bar| foo.append(bar.some_rel) end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) method:

```
foo = bars.map(&:some_rel)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
foo = bars.map { |bar| bar.some_rel }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible, like in Python, to create an array from a loop in just one line? Can I make the following code in to just one line?
>
> ```
>  foo = []
>  bars.each do |bar| foo.append(bar.some_rel) end
> ```

I never understand what the obsession is with doing something in one line, but, yes, in Ruby, you can create an array from a loop in just one line. In fact, in Ruby, you can do *everything* in one line. Just replace all linebreaks with semicolons:

```
 foo = []; bars.each do |bar| foo.append(bar.some_rel) end
```

For example, this is a web framework called [Camping](https://camping.github.io/camping.io/):

```
require"uri";require"rack";class Object;def meta_def m,&b;(class<<self;self end).send:define_method,m,&b end end;module Camping;C=self;S=IO.read(__FILE__)rescue nil;P="<h1>Cam\ping Problem!</h1><h2>%s</h2>";U=Rack::Utils;O={};Apps=[];SK=:camping;class H<Hash;def method_missing m,*a;m.to_s=~/=$/?self[$`]=a[0]:a==[]?self[m.to_s]:super end;undef id,type if ??==63 end;class Cookies<H;attr_accessor :_p;def _n;@n||={}end;alias _s []=;def set k,v,o={};_s(j=k.to_s,v);_n[j]={:value=>v,:path=>_p}.update o;end;def []=(k,v)set(k,v,v.is_a?(Hash)?v:{})end end;module Helpers;def R c,*g;p,h=/\(.+?\)/,g.grep(Hash);g-=h;raise"bad route"if !u=c.urls.find{|x|break x if x.scan(p).size==g.size&&/^#{x}\/?$/=~(x=g.inject(x){|x,a|x.sub p,U.escape((a.to_param rescue a))}.gsub(/\\(.)/){$1})};h.any?? u+"?"+U.build_query(h[0]):u end;def / p;p[0]==?/?@root+p :p end;def URL c='/',*a;c=R(c,*a) if c.respond_to?(:urls);c=self/c;c=@request.url[/.{8,}?(?=\/|$)/]+c if c[0]==?/;URI c end end; module Base;attr_accessor:env,:request,:root,:input,:cookies,:state,:status,:headers,:body;T={};L=:layout;def lookup n;T.fetch(n.to_sym){|k|t=Views.method_defined?(k)||(t=O[:_t].keys.grep(/^#{n}\./)[0]and Template[t].new{O[:_t][t]})||(f=Dir[[O[:views]||"views","#{n}.*"]*'/'][0])&&Template.new(f,O[f[/\.(\w+)$/,1].to_sym]||{});O[:dynamic_templates]?t: T[k]=t} end;def render v,*a,&b;if t=lookup(v);r=@_r;@_r=o=Hash===a[-1]?a.pop: {};s=(t==true)?mab{send v,*a,&b}: t.render(self,o[:locals]||{},&b);s=render(L,o.merge(L=>false)){s}if o[L]or o[L].nil?&&lookup(L)&&!r&&v.to_s[0]!=?_;s;else;raise"no template: #{v}"end;end;def mab &b;extend(Mab);mab(&b) end;def r s,b,h={};b,h=h,b if Hash===b;@status=s;@headers.merge!(h);@body=b end;def redirect *a;r 302,'','Location'=>URL(*a).to_s end;def r404 p;P%"#{p} not found"end;def r500 k,m,e;raise e end;def r501 m;P%"#{m.upcase} not implemented"end;def serve(p,c)(t=Rack::Mime.mime_type p[/\..*$/],"text/html")&&@headers["Content-Type"]=t;c;end;def to_a;@env['rack.session'][SK]=Hash[@state];r=Rack::Response.new(@body,@status,@headers);@cookies._n.each{|k,v|r.set_cookie k,v};r.to_a end;def initialize(env,m)r=@request=Rack:: Request.new(@env=env);@root,@input,@cookies,@state,@headers,@status,@method=r.script_name.sub(/\/$/,''),n(r.params),Cookies[r.cookies],H[r.session[SK]||{}],{'Content-Type'=>'text/html'},m=~/r(\d+)/?$1.to_i: 200,m;@cookies._p=self/"/" end;def n h;Hash===h ?h.inject(H[]){|m,(k,v)|m[k]=n(v);m}: h end;def service *a;r=catch(:halt){send(@method,*a)};@body||=r;self end end;module Controllers;@r=[];class<<self;def R *u;r=@r;Class.new{meta_def(:urls){u};meta_def(:inherited){|x|r<<x}}end;def D p,m,e;p='/'if !p||!p[0];(a=O[:_t].find{|n,_|n==p}) and return [I,:serve,*a];@r.map{|k|k.urls.map{|x|return(k.method_defined? m)?[k,m,*$~[1..-1].map{|x|U.unescape x}]:[I, 'r501',m]if p=~/^#{x}\/?$/}};[I,'r404',p] end;N=H.new{|_,x|x.downcase}.merge!("N"=>'(\d+)',"X"=>'([^/]+)',"Index"=>'');def M;def M;end;constants.map{|c|k=const_get(c);k.send:include,C,X,Base,Helpers,Models;@r=[k]+@r if @r-[k]==@r;k.meta_def(:urls){["/#{c.to_s.scan(/.[^A-Z]*/).map(&N.method(:[]))*'/'}"]}if !k.respond_to?:urls}end end;I=R()end;X=Controllers;class<<self;def goes m,g=TOPLEVEL_BINDING;Apps<<a=eval(S.gsub(/Camping/,m.to_s),g);caller[0]=~/:/;IO.read(a.set:__FILE__,$`)=~/^__END__/&&(b=$'.split /^@@\s*(.+?)\s*\r?\n/m).shift rescue nil;a.set :_t,H[*b||[]];end;def call e;X.M;k,m,*a=X.D e["PATH_INFO"],e['REQUEST_METHOD'].downcase,e;k.new(e,m).service(*a).to_a;rescue;r500(:I,k,m,$!,:env=>e).to_a end;def method_missing m,c,*a;X.M;h=Hash===a[-1]?a.pop: {};e=H[Rack::MockRequest.env_for('',h.delete(:env)||{})];k=X.const_get(c).new(e,m.to_s);h.each{|i,v|k.send"#{i}=",v};k.service(*a) end;def use*a,&b;m=a.shift.new(method(:call),*a,&b);meta_def(:call){|e|m.call(e)}end;def options;O end;def set k,v;O[k]=v end end;module Views;include X,Helpers end;module Models;autoload:Base,'camping/ar';Helpers.send:include,X,self end;autoload:Mab,'camping/mab';autoload:Template,'camping/template';C end
```

See? One line!

Comment: "I never understand what the obsession is with doing something in one line". Readability. `foo = bars.map(&:some_rel)` is  just beautiful.

Comment: But that doesn't come from it being written on one line. It comes from using idiomatic Ruby, high-level abstractions and good object-oriented design. Do you find [this](https://github.com/camping/camping/blob/master/lib/camping-unabridged.rb) more readable or the version I posted in my answer? It's the *exact identical* code, except with all linebreaks removed and thus written on one line. You claim the one-line version is more readable, I disagree.

Comment: No I don't. But creating an array from a loop is something you do a lot. Once you learn it, you instantly understand what it does. It being shorter makes it faster to read and understand. At least that's how it is for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible, like in Python, to create an array from a loop in just one line?

Ruby will let you do whatever you want in as many lines as you want.

If you would like, just put a semi-colon at the end of each 'line', and you can write each statement on the same line.

When you're using one line for `Array#each`, you should use `{` and `}` as the block delimiters. It doesn't really matter; it's just best practice.

With `Array#each`, you can't do:

```
foo = bar.each{|x| x.some_rel}
```

This is because `Array#each` **always** returns `nil`.

Like another answer said, for your purposes you may want to use `Array#map` because `#map` returns an array. So you **can** do this:

```
foo = bar.map{|x| x.some_rel}
```

Because `map` **returns** something.

That'll get it into one line. If you really want overkill, you can write the entire program in a single line like so:

```
foo = []; foo.do_something; foo.do_something_else; bar.whatever;
```

But it looks ugly and won't be **readable**. Ruby is all about readability.